# UItabBar changing View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

i have some difficulties changing tab bar controllers. Basically I have UITabBarController with 3 controllers. First time when app starts. I change one controller like this:

```
NSMutableArray *muteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
FirstPage *online;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{

    online =[[FirstPage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];


}else{

    online =[[FirstPage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}

//adding all controllers of tab bar to array
[muteArray addObjectsFromArray:_navigationCotroller.viewControllers];
online.tabBarControllers = [muteArray copy];
//replacing object of login controller to after login controller
[muteArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:online];


[online release];

//setting new controllers to tab bar
[_navigationCotroller setViewControllers:muteArray animated:YES];

[muteArray release];
```

Then in FirstPage controller i do some change and press OK. Now i need to change controllers again, doing this:

```
NSLog(@"Before change Tab Bar cotrollers = %@",self.tabBarController.viewControllers);

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:_tabBarControllers animated:YES];

NSLog(@"After change Tab Bar cotrollers = %@",self.tabBarController.viewControllers);

[self.tabBarController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

_tabBarControllers is array of controllers which i saved when app started.

This code change controllers, but when i want to open changed controller with setSelectedIndex it don't work.

Any ideas ?

And print this:

Before change Tab Bar cotrollers = NULL
After change Tab Bar cotrollers = NULL

Comment: _navigationCotroller is a typo in your code too?

Comment: _navigationCotroller is main UITabBarController

Comment: mind the missing "N" character there ;) _navigationCotroller --> _navigationCoNtroller

Comment: it's more than a little confusing to call a tabBarController navigationController. Everyone reading this will assume that navigationController is a navigation controller. I would recommend you call your tabBarController myTabBarController

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I assume you meant:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Failing that it sounds like the problem is with your _tabBarControllers.

what do the following output:

```
NSLog(@" _tabBarControllers count = %d", [_tabBarControllers count]);
NSArray* newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
NSLog(@" newArray count = %d", [newArray count]);
```

EDIT:
Does the following successfully remove the first tab with no problems?

```
NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[newArray removeObjectAtIndex:0]; 
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newArray animated:YES];
```

EDIT 2 :

try changing:

```
[muteArray addObjectsFromArray:_navigationCotroller.viewControllers];
online.tabBarControllers = [muteArray copy];
[muteArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:online];
```

to:

```
[muteArray addObjectsFromArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[muteArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:online];
online.tabBarControllers = [muteArray copy];
```

To be honest I'm finding it hard to follow your app structure and object references.

Comment: _tabBarControllers count = 3

newArray count = 3


and 


Before change Tab Bar cotrollers = (

    "<UINavigationController: 0x6d15710>",

    "<FirstPage: 0x882b200>",

    "<UINavigationController: 0x6d183d0>"

)

After change Tab Bar cotrollers = (null)

Comment: Without seeing your code where you create _tabBarControllers it's difficult to help.

Comment: there is above code:

online.tabBarControllers = [muteArray copy];

here i copy all default created controllers.

Comment: Yes the code above remove first tab bar controller with no problem

Comment: I have UItabBarController with UINavigationController 's inside. this line  NSLog(@"---> %@",[[appDelegate.navigationTabBarCotroller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]); 


---> (
    "<AfterLoginView: 0xb856070>",
    "<FirstPage: 0x699acb0>"
)
prints: