# How can we show new screen without pushing view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose we have tab-bar project with two tabs "Tab A" and "Tab B", and "viewController A"  and "viewController B". and have 1 button on each screen to navigate to another screen,

I want to show another screen on button click (its easy) , but i want to show another screen without pushing view (without creating back button on screen on which we jump)

like we navigate in tab bar , when we click on tab-bar button we go to screen without creating back button on another screen

But I want to do same with normal button

Answer (score 0):

Two ways;

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

Or

```
[self.view addSubview:second.view];
```

If you don't want to do this kinds of thing and meaning different, you could use this;

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.window.rootViewController = secondVC;
```

Comment: thanks, but i do not want to subclass, i want same functionality like as tabbar

Comment: Ya it works , but it hides tab-bar, i have just updated my question it may create more clarity

Comment: app.window.rootViewController = tab2;(it is assuming first rootviewcontroller is tab1)

Comment: yes right , but problem is that , when we do this, it hides tab-bar controller

Comment: check out this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878623/uitabbar-changing-view-controllers