# Change View controllers of UITabbarController according to type of user role in an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Thanks in advance.
I am making an iOS app in Objective C. In the app user can login as a JobSeeker or Employer. After login user can switch the role from setting page. I am using UITabBarController with 5 tabs. 
So my question is after changing the role (after login when user uses the app) from setting page how will I change the TabBarController's view controllers.

Comment: it depends on how you use UITabBarController, add the code for that

Comment: Can you tell me in detail? Just any login I will implement.

Comment: show your storyboard screenshot.

Comment: make 2 TabBarController in storyboard Just change root view controller when user change role.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8878964/1308632

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass of `UITabBarController`. And assign this class to your tabbar controller in your storyboard if you are using it.

Then in viewDidLoad method of your tabbar controller class, you can instantiate corresponding view controllers for each of your tabs. What view controllers you want to instantiate are depending on user roles. This is the swift code, you can do it similarly with objective-c:

```
 if userIsJobSeeker {
     //I split each tab's view controller to a separated storyboard file
     let firstTabStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourFirstTab", bundle: nil)
     let firstTabNav = firstTabStoryBoard .instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
     firstTabNav .tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "JobSeekerFirstTab", image: UIImage(named: "whatever"), selectedImage: nil)
     //do it similarly with other tabs
    self.viewControllers = [firstTabNav, secondTabNav, thirdTabNav, otherTabNav]
 } else {
     //different tabs for other role.
 }
```